# Using a named range in VBA to create a dynamic priority list

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a list of the top 5 priorities for a list of tasks based on their current status, I am using some for loops and if functions to do this. However, I am using a list of statuses from a named range (which works as a cell function using the sumproduct function) but when I run the code it does not register when a cell is equal to a value in the list.

"Priorities_Team" is a named range consisting of about 6 different cells but this needs to be able to change as there may be more or less in future, which is why I used the named range.

I have also tried substituting the named range for a static range but this did not help the situation.

Is there an issue with the way that the function is written in VBA?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Num_Cells As Integer
Dim Running_Total As Integer
Dim i_Item_No As String
Dim i_Description As String
Dim i_Current_Status As String

Num_Cells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A1000"))

Running_Total = 1

For i = 2 To Num_Cells
    Sheet1.Select
    If Running_Total < 6 Then
        i_Item_No = Cells(i, 1).Value
        i_Description = Cells(i, 2).Value
        i_Current_Status = Cells(i, 3).Value
    
        If WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Cells(i, 3).Value = Priorities_Team)) > 0 Then
            Running_Total = Running_Total + 1
            Sheet2.Select
            Cells(Running_Total, 1).Value = i_Item_No
            Cells(Running_Total, 2).Value = i_Description
            Cells(Running_Total, 3).Value = i_Current_Status
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code has worked for me but I have not been able to use a named range to achieve this.

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim Num_Cells As Integer
Dim i_Output As String
Dim Running_Total As Integer
Dim i_Item_No As String
Dim i_Description As String
Dim i_Current_Status As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim Team_Last_Status As String

'Getting the number of Tasks in the sheet
Num_Cells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A1000"))

'Getting the number of status's in the list
Team_Last_Status = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E3:E20"))

Running_Total = 1

For i = 2 To Num_Cells
    Sheet1.Select
    If Running_Total < 6 Then
        i_Item_No = Cells(i, 1).Value
        i_Description = Cells(i, 2).Value
        i_Current_Status = Cells(i, 3).Value
    
        For x = 1 To Team_Last_Status + 2
            If i_Current_Status = Cells(x, 5).Value Then
                    Running_Total = Running_Total + 1
                    Sheet2.Select
                    Cells(Running_Total, 1).Value = i_Item_No
                    Cells(Running_Total, 2).Value = i_Description
                    Cells(Running_Total, 3).Value = i_Current_Status
            End If
        Next x

    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```